# Mocking Strategies

Tags: java, mocking

I have been analyzing about Mocking and mocking frameworks recently.  I find that the mocking frameworks have evolved over time.  JMock to EasyMock to Mockito and even TypeMock, each of these frameworks use their own strategies for mocking.  Some make the use of interfaces mandatory while others support mocking concrete classes.

My Question:  Does anyone have any document or any pointers to articles that discuss in detail about the various mocking strategies?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an [article](http://www.slideshare.net/subin123/easymock-tutorial) which explains different kinds of Mocking.  So there are basically two types of mechanism used in mocking,

1. Proxy based method - used in easymock
2. Remapping class files in class loader - used in jmockit, powermock

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article entitled ["Mocks Aren't Stubs"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) by Martin Fowler interesting.
 It talks about the main differences between classical and mockist approaches of tests.

Answer (score 0):

The book - x-Unit test patterns by Gerhard Mezzaros discusses in detail about different types of test-doubles.  Different mocking strategies however are not discussed anywhere.  May I am still missing the right article.  I am planning to create one very soon so that it will be useful to everyone.